# cordova iOS triplicating plist resource

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have a cordova project that include the iOS platform.

As part of `config.xml` for `platform="ios"` I need to copy in `GoogleService-Info.plist` into the project.

I am doing this as follows:

```
<resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist"/>
```

I have also tried the following variation

```
<resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" target-dir="Resources"/>
```

The file is being copied to `platforms/ios/RMCv2dev/Resources` correctly but around 50% of the time it doesn't build with `cordova build ios`, with `CopyPlistFile` complaining it can't remove `GoogleService-Info.plist` from the build output, though oddly sometimes it does build.

```
CopyPlistFile /Users/adf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMCv2dev-azdfkixnsmcojlhkzhmfjdrtncns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RMCv2dev/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/RMCv2dev.app/GoogleService-Info.plist RMCv2dev/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist
cd /Users/adf/Sites/RMC2/dev/BZ95599/Cordova/RMCv2dev/platforms/ios
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/adf/android-sdks/tools:/Users/adf/android-sdks/platform-tools:/Users/adf/bin:/Users/adf/Projects/Chromium/depot_tools"
builtin-copyPlist --convert binary1 --outdir /Users/adf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMCv2dev-azdfkixnsmcojlhkzhmfjdrtncns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RMCv2dev/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/RMCv2dev.app -- RMCv2dev/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist

error: failed to remove /Users/adf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RMCv2dev-azdfkixnsmcojlhkzhmfjdrtncns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/RMCv2dev/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/RMCv2dev.app/GoogleService-Info.plist: “GoogleService-Info.plist” couldn’t be removed.
```

In Xcode it also does not build fairly consistently.

I can see that `GoogleService-Info.plist` is listed 3 times.  If I remove two of them, the project will then build.

While writing this question, I have managed to work out that every time I run `cordova build ios` it is adding another reference to `GoogleService-Info.plist` so I think that is the source of my problem.

But what could be causing that behaviour?

I can confirm, with `<resource-file>` in `config.xml` `GoogleService-Info.plist` is added to the project every time build is run.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in `cordova-ios 4.4.0` fixed in `cordova-ios 4.5.1`

Update `config.xml` and set `<engine name="iso" spec="^4.5.1"/>`

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13112